# python script doesnot run through java command

Tags: java, python-2.7, processbuilder

```
String command = "C:/Python27/python E:/4N/Final year project/MiningResume-master/MiningResume-master/parser.py";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

The code compiles but does not run the script.How to run a python script in java project using java command?

Comment: good resolution for your issue :[Three ways to run Python programs from Java](https://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/949995-three-ways-run-python-programs-java)

Comment: @HarshaPathak was your problem solved ?

Comment: No.The code compiles without errors but does not run the python file.

Answer (score 0):

You have issue with your command string. The folder name `Final year project` has spaces, in that case you need to pass the python file location in double quote.

So, you need to change your command string, where double quote has been escaped.

```
String command = "C:/Python27/python \"E:/4N/Final year project/MiningResume-master/MiningResume-master/parser.py\"";
```